# jQuery ajax fail always triggered (even in success)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My page does a lot of ajax requests. Like this:

```
function getSpecificData(start,end){
    var link = generateLink('open', start, end);
    getAjaxData(link).done(function(data) {
        //save data to array
        //function that does pagination
        renderEvents(); //starts treating events on the new fields
    }).fail($.toaster({ priority : 'danger', title : 'Tickets', message : 'The server monkeys misplaced the tickets'}));
}
```

There's a previous function that I call that generates the link and does this. Here's the getAjaxData method

```
function getAjaxData(link) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : link,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

The problem: whenever I load the page OR I redo those ajax requests at the click of a button the toaster notifications always pop up. The fail case is always triggered, even if a split second later the request is completed successfully.

Question: What am I doing wrong that's causing the fail to be triggered right after the request? It's supposed to only trigger if the request actually fails, not when it's in progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your fail code in an anonymous function so it always executes.

```
function getSpecificData(start,end){
    var link = generateLink('open', start, end);
    getAjaxData(link).done(function(data) {
        //save data to array
        //function that does pagination
        renderEvents(); //starts treating events on the new fields
    }).fail(function(){
      $.toaster({ priority : 'danger', title : 'Tickets', message : 'The server monkeys misplaced the tickets'})
    });
}
```

Comment: of course, such a simple error... now I feel ridiculous for not seeing that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Thaenor: I initially missed it too, so don't be too hard on yourself :)

Comment: you're right, it's not really a sugary syntax there, it's easy to miss. Anyway, thanks a lot, you just saved my users an initial (and unneeded) jump scare of toasters :D

Comment: *Always unplug your toaster from the wall before sticking a knife in it* :)

Comment: _wise words my friend ;)_